# Write to UTF-8 file in Python

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, byte-order-mark

I'm really confused with the `codecs.open function`. When I do:

```
file = codecs.open("temp", "w", "utf-8")
file.write(codecs.BOM_UTF8)
file.close()
```

It gives me the error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position
>   0: ordinal not in range(128)

If I do:

```
file = open("temp", "w")
file.write(codecs.BOM_UTF8)
file.close()
```

It works fine.

**Question** is why does the first method fail? And how do I insert the bom?

If the second method is the correct way of doing it, what the point of using `codecs.open(filename, "w", "utf-8")`?

Comment: Don’t use a BOM in UTF-8.  ***Please.***

Comment: @tchrist Huh? Why not?

Comment: @SalmanPK BOM is not needed in UTF-8 and only adds complexity (e.g. you can't just concatenate BOM'd files and result with valid text).  See [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom); don't miss the big comment under Q

Answer (score 313, accepted):

I believe the problem is that [`codecs.BOM_UTF8`](https://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.BOM_UTF8) is a byte string, not a Unicode string. I suspect the file handler is trying to guess what you really mean based on "I'm meant to be writing Unicode as UTF-8-encoded text, but you've given me a byte string!"

Try writing the Unicode string for the byte order mark (i.e. Unicode U+FEFF) directly, so that the file just encodes that as UTF-8:

```
import codecs

file = codecs.open("lol", "w", "utf-8")
file.write(u'\ufeff')
file.close()
```

(That seems to give the right answer - a file with bytes EF BB BF.)

EDIT: S. Lott's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/934203/12892) of using "utf-8-sig" as the encoding is a better one than explicitly writing the BOM yourself, but I'll leave this answer here as it explains what was going wrong before.

Comment: Warning: open and open is not the same. If you do "from codecs import open", it will NOT be the same as you would simply type "open".

Comment: you can also use codecs.open('test.txt', 'w', 'utf-8-sig') instead

Comment: I'm getting "TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)". I don't understand what we're doing here. Can someone please help? I need to append a string (paragraph) to a text file. Do I need to convert that into an integer first before writing?

Comment: @Mugen: The *exact* code I've written works fine as far as I can see. I suggest you ask a new question showing *exactly* what code you've got, and where the error occurs.

Comment: @Mugen you need to call `codecs.open` instead of just `open`

Answer (score 201):

Read the following:  http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#module-encodings.utf_8_sig

Do this

```
with codecs.open("test_output", "w", "utf-8-sig") as temp:
    temp.write("hi mom\n")
    temp.write(u"This has ♭")
```

The resulting file is UTF-8 with the expected BOM.

Comment: Thanks. That worked (Windows 7 x64, Python 2.7.5 x64). This solution works well when you open the file in mode "a" (append).

Comment: This didn't work for me, Python 3 on Windows. I had to do this instead with open(file_name, 'wb') as bomfile:
            bomfile.write(codecs.BOM_UTF8) then re-open the file for append.

Comment: @user2905353: not required; this is handled by [context management](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) of `open`.

Comment: Solve my problem. Mac os python script copy to windows running success.

Answer (score 65):

It is very simple just use this. **Not any library needed.**

```
with open('text.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Answer (score 12):

@S-Lott gives the right procedure, but expanding on the *Unicode* issues, the *Python* interpreter can provide more insights.

Jon Skeet is right (unusual) about the [`codecs`](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.BOM) module - it contains byte strings:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.BOM
'\xff\xfe'
>>> codecs.BOM_UTF8
'\xef\xbb\xbf'
>>>
```

Picking another nit, the `BOM` has a standard *Unicode* name, and it can be entered as:

```
>>> bom= u"\N{ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE}"
>>> bom
u'\ufeff'
```

It is also accessible via [`unicodedata`](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html#module-unicodedata):

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.lookup('ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE')
u'\ufeff'
>>>
```

Answer (score 10):

I use the file *nix command to convert a unknown charset file in a utf-8 file

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

# converting a unknown formatting file in utf-8

import codecs
import commands

file_location = "jumper.sub"
file_encoding = commands.getoutput('file -b --mime-encoding %s' % file_location)

file_stream = codecs.open(file_location, 'r', file_encoding)
file_output = codecs.open(file_location+"b", 'w', 'utf-8')

for l in file_stream:
    file_output.write(l)

file_stream.close()
file_output.close()
```

Comment: Use `# coding: utf8` instead of  `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`which is far easier to remember.

Comment: I am really interested in seing something like that working on windows

Answer (score 1):

python 3.4 >= using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
import pathlib
pathlib.Path("text.txt").write_text(text, encoding='utf-8') #or utf-8-sig for BOM
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def read_files(file_path):
    
        with open(file_path, encoding='utf8') as f:
            text = f.read()
            return text

**OR (AND)**

    def read_files(text, file_path):
    
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            f.write(text.encode('utf8', 'ignore'))

 **OR**

    document = Document()
    document.add_heading(file_path.name, 0)
        file_path.read_text(encoding='UTF-8'))
            file_content = file_path.read_text(encoding='UTF-8')
            document.add_paragraph(file_content)

**OR**

    def read_text_from_file(cale_fisier):
        text = cale_fisier.read_text(encoding='UTF-8')
        print("what I read: ", text)
        return text # return written text
    
    def save_text_into_file(cale_fisier, text):
        f = open(cale_fisier, "w", encoding = 'utf-8') # open file
        print("Ce am scris: ", text)
        f.write(text) # write the content to the file

**OR**

    def read_text_from_file(file_path):
        with open(file_path, encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as f:
            text = f.read()
            return text # return written text

**OR**

    def write_to_file(text, file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(text.encode('utf8', 'ignore')) # write the content to the file
```

[SOURCE HERE:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character/)

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import re
import chardet

def read_text_from_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        raw_data = f.read()

    try:
        # Încercăm să decodăm ca UTF-8, ignorând erorile
        return raw_data.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        pass

    # Dacă UTF-8 eșuează, încercăm detectarea automată a codificării
    encoding = chardet.detect(raw_data)['encoding']
    if encoding is not None:
        try:
            return raw_data.decode(encoding, errors='ignore')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            pass

    raise Exception(f"Eroare: Nu s-a putut decodifica fișierul {file_path} nici cu UTF-8, nici cu codificarea detectată.")



def write_to_file(text, file_path, encoding='utf8'):
    """
    Aceasta functie scrie un text intr-un fisier.
    text: textul pe care vrei sa il scrii
    file_path: calea catre fisierul in care vrei sa scrii
    """
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(text.encode(encoding, 'ignore'))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Comment: That was a full code, with an example how to open/close a UTF-8 file with Python

Answer (score -3):

If you are using Pandas I/O methods like pandas.to_excel(), add an encoding parameter, e.g.

```
pd.to_excel("somefile.xlsx", sheet_name="export", encoding='utf-8')
```

This works for most international characters I believe.