# self.writer.writerow([s.encode('utf-8') for s in row])

Tags: python

I am trying to write into a file (in Python), but it says:

> 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'encode'

Here is the code:

```
self.writer.writerow([s.encode('utf-8') for s in row])
```

Is there a way to avoid/fix this ?

Comment: Just do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934160/write-to-utf-8-file-in-python

Comment: @SimpleCoder: The csv module doesn't support unicode -> http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: yeah, but it says: "Accordingly, all input should be UTF-8 or printable ASCII to be safe;..." which is my case. the thing is that my 's' object is not a unicode object, i should change it to unicode object.

Comment: the thing is: 
it is working fine with thise code: w.writerow([u"%d"%s.id,s.name,u"%d"%s.clicks,s.status,s.stand.nick])
but not with this one: 
w.writerow([u"%d"%s.id,s.name,u"%d"%s.clicks,s.status,s.stand.nick,s.studiengaenge])
because 'studiengaenge' purportedly isnot a unicode object. can that be a reason for my problem.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your code

```
self.writer.writerow([s.encode('utf-8') for s in row])
```

the "s" object may not a unicode object 
you should try change your "s" object to unicode first