# CSV Module - write German to CSV in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm reading german names from a csv, and want to write them in a csv file, with the right encoding for ä, ö and ü. Reading works fine, but when I write to the csv, the characters are displayed like this: LÃ¶ffler.

```
reader1 = csv.reader(open('names.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',')
```

What do I need to add to my writer to get the right encoding?

```
    outfile.write('K:' + n + ',' + a + ',' + '-' + '\n')
```

I tried unicodecsv, but can't get it to work:

```
w = unicodecsv.writer(outfile, encoding='utf-8')
w.write('K:' + n + ',' + a + ',' + '-' + '\n')
```

Error message:

```
AttributeError: 'UnicodeWriter' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Comment: what encoding does your file names.csv have?

Answer (score 1):

In `python2.X` your best bet is using tool like [unicodecsv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/), as `csv` module in this python handles only `acsii`.

On Python3+ you'll get this ot of the box, just pass proper encoding to the [open](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function.

Comment: Please look into csv module API, this module allows you to write rows of data (that is arrays) using `writer.writerow` function, while you are trying to write line by hand.

Comment: This worked, however, encoding still doesn't work! Can you point me to an easy example of how to use unicodecsv with csv writer?

Comment: You need to use `unicodecsv` both to read and write the csv file. Encoding might get lost at any point. 

Please post working example of your code, I might spot problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must change the encoding of the file. I think UTF-8 should work.
Do you use Java?
[Here someone showed how it should work.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1001568/3074828)

Comment: this is for Java, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, you use Python, or?

Comment: Maybe, this helps you: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934160/write-to-utf-8-file-in-python)