# Output chinese in csv and opened with excel is gibberish in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, encoding, scrapy

Hi everyone~ I'm new to python ~ Does anyone know that I can crawl the data(the string mix with Chinese and English) into python_job.csv and I can open with excel but the Chinese part all become gibberish, ***but the bad situation only happened in csv*** , if I open with notepad or txt it works in normally, I try for .decode('unicode_escape') or .encode('unicode_escape') that I can encode the chinese into unicode but I still can not transfer them into normal way.

```
def get_link(self,response):
                        global get_par
                        data = json.loads(response.body)
                        total_count = int(data['TOTALPAGE'])
                        for detail in data['data']:
                           for value in detail.values():
                                try:
                                    if value.index(u'Python') or value.index('Python') or value.index('python') or value.index(u'python'):
                                        item = Article()
                                        item['name'] = detail['JOB']
                                        item['link'] = 'http://www.104.com.tw/jobbank/cust_job/job.cfm?j=' + detail['J']
                                        item['content'] = detail['DESCRIPTION']
                                        item['skill'] = detail['OTHERS']
                                        global f_pos, col
                                        for i in title:
                                                if i is 'name':
                                                        f_pos.loc[col,i] = item['name']
                                                elif i is 'link':
                                                        f_pos.loc[col,i] = item['link']
                                                elif i is 'content':
                                                        f_pos.loc[col,i] = item['name']
                                                else:
                                                     f_pos.loc[col,i] = item['skill']
                                                     col = col + 1
                                        yield item
                                except Exception,e:
                                        print e
                        global count
                        count = count + 1
                        if count <= total_count:
                                yield Request(                                               
                                url='http://www.104.com.tw/i/apis/jobsearch.cfm?kws=研發替代役&page='+ str(count) +'&'+ get_par,
                                dont_filter=True,
                                callback=self.get_link
                                )
                        else:
                                f_pos.to_csv('python_job.csv',columns=title, encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with Excel, not with your Python code.  Try putting in a BOM at the beginning of the file, though. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934160/write-to-utf-8-file-in-python

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I will try that. By the way, I opened with notepad and select the item of 'transfer the encoding into  utf-8 ' and then it works out !

Comment: I'm guessing that amounts to what I suggested; personally, I would prefer a solution which can be easily automated.

Comment: I wish I can do it automatically,but I still trying ~ haha, thank you very much :D