# python write unicode to file easily?

Tags: python, file, unicode

I want to make sure all string are unicode in my code, so I use `unicode_literals`, then I need to write string to file:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
with open('/tmp/test', 'wb') as f:
    f.write("中文") # UnicodeEncodeError
```

so I need to do this:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
with open('/tmp/test', 'wb') as f:
    f.write("中文".encode("utf-8"))
    f.write("中文".encode("utf-8"))
    f.write("中文".encode("utf-8"))
    f.write("中文".encode("utf-8"))
```

but every time I need to encode in code, I am lazy, so I change to codecs:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from codecs import open
import locale, codecs
lang, encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()

with open('/tmp/test', 'wb', encoding) as f:
    f.write("中文")
```

**still I think this is too much if I just want to write to file, any easier method?**

Comment: related: [Python: write Unicode text to a text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6048085/4279)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to call `.encode()` and you don't need to call `locale.getdefaultlocale()` explicitly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import io

with io.open('/tmp/test', 'w') as file:
    file.write(u"中文" * 4)
```

It uses `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` character encoding to save Unicode text to the file.

On Python 3:

- you don't need to use the explicit encoding declaration  (`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`), to use literal non-ascii characters in your Python source code. `utf-8` is the default.
- you don't need to use `import io`: builtin `open()` is `io.open()` there
- you don't need to use `u''` (`u` prefix). `''` literals are Unicode by default. If you want to omit `u''` then put back `from __future__ import unicode_literals` as in your code in the question.

i.e., the complete Python 3 code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

with open('/tmp/test', 'w') as file:
    file.write("中文" * 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution?

[Write to UTF-8 file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934160/write-to-utf-8-file-in-python)

Only three lines of code.