# SPSS-Python write to CSV - wrong encoding when opening in Excel

Tags: python, excel, csv, encoding, spss

In SPSS, using python, I am writing a list of lists into a csv file:

```
begin program.

import spss,spssaux, sys, csv, codecs

def WriteDim():

    MyArray=[some list of lists]
    for MyVar in MyFile.varlist:
        MyArray.append([MyVar.name,MyVar.label])

    DimFile="DimCSV.csv"

    with codecs.open(DimFile, "w",encoding='utf8') as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output,  lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerows(MyArray)

end program.
```

I have some Spanish text in my practice array, for example `"reparación"`. If I open the output file in a text editor, all looks fine. However, if I open it in Excel 2016, it looks like this: `"reparaciÃ³n"`. I would need to go to Data/Import From text" and **manually** choose UTF encoding, but this is not an option for the future users of my SPSS program.

Is there any way of writing the file so that Excel will open it using UTF-8 encoding ?
It has to be a csv file - opening it in excel is only one use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You** explicitely ask for a utf8 encoding at `codecs.open(DimFile, "w",encoding='utf8')`, and later say you would prefere not to use utf8. Just directly use the expected encoding:

```
with codecs.open(DimFile, "w",encoding='cp1252') as output:
```

(cp1252 is the common encoding for Spanish on Windows)

Comment: I said I prefer to not choose the encoding manually when opening in Excel; I assumed UTF-8 would work, so I saved the file as UTF but it seems that Excel, as default, does not open the file as UTF. The problem is that Excel does not use the file encoding to open it

Comment: @horace_vr: Excel uses by default the system encoding which is commonly win-1252 code page for west european language systems. Why do you want to use utf8 encoding on Windows?

Comment: I am looking into a way to save those texts. I assumed UTF-8 would do the trick, but apprentice no. win-1252 is not a valid encoding for the python program, as far as I can see

Answer (score 0):

While Serge Ballesta's answer worked perfectly for Spanish, I found that `encoding='utf-8-sig'` works best for all characters I tested. I felt UTF-8 should be used, as it is more common than the other suggested encodings.

Credit to this topic:
[Write to UTF-8 file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934160/write-to-utf-8-file-in-python)