# How to write a iadx or text file with BOM in python

Tags: python, byte-order-mark

I want to use BOM with UTF-8. But it only saves files in UTF-8. What can I do ?I'm rather new, could you please write an answer as an addition to the sample code I shared directly?

```
import os
import codecs
a=1

filelist=os.listdir("name")
for file in filelist:
    filelen=len(os.listdir("name/"+file))
    if filelen==10:
        with open(file + ".iadx", "w", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
            f.write("<name>")
            f.write("\n")
            f.write('something')
```

Comment: Why do you need a BOM in UTF-8? It's not required or recommended.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write to UTF-8 file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934160/write-to-utf-8-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

From [Python documentation on `codecs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) (search for "-sig") :

> On encoding the utf-8-sig codec will write `0xef`, `0xbb`, `0xbf` as the first three bytes to the file.

So just doing :

```py
with open(file + ".iadx", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
#                                             ^^^^
```

will do the trick.